# Django changing date format is not working

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

I decided to change the date format from `YYYY-mm-dd` to `%d %b %Y` something like `10 Jan 2023`

However, i have tried many things and it all seem to fail, let's start with settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = False

USE_TZ = True
USE_L10N = False

DATE_FORMAT ='%d %b %Y'
```

the model:

```py
class DateModel(models.Model):
      date = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True,blank=False)
      desc = models.CharField()
```

the serializer:

```py
from appname import models
class DateSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           model = models.DateModel
           fields = '__all__' # alternatively 'date','desc',
```

the view:

```py
from rest_framework import views
from appname import serializer #importing the serializer file 
from django.utils import timezone,dateformat
from appname import models
from django.conf import settings

class DateView(views.APIView):
      serializer_class = serializer.DateSerializer
      def get(self,request):
          return Response(serializer.DateSerializer(models.DateModel.objects.all().data),status=200)
      def post(self,request):
         data = serializer.DateSerializer(data=request.data)
         if data.is_valid():
            desc = data.data['desc']
            date = dateformat.format(timezone.now(),settings.DATE_FORMAT)
            model_instance = models.DateModel.objects.create(date=date,desc=desc)
            model_instance.save()
            return Response("Posted!",status=200)
         return Response("Invalid Data, 400 status code error is raised",status=400)
```

and when i submit a post and try to view it, i get the date in this format `2023-01-10`, as i mentioned before, but i am aiming for this format `10-Jan-2023`

Comment: The `DATE_FORMAT` is not about the model layer, only the forms, serializers, etc. So you can not construct a `DateModel` object with this.

Comment: how do you suggest i change the format in the model layer then?

Comment: you don't. You can simply pass a `date` object anway when you create it.

Answer (score 1):

The `DATE_FORMAT` is not about the model layer, only the forms, serializers, etc. So you can not construct a `DateModel` object with this.

It is here not necessary anyway, you can just pass a `date` object:

```
from appname import models, serializer
from django.utils import timezone
from rest_framework import views


class DateView(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = serializer.DateSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        return Response(
            serializer.DateSerializer(models.DateModel.objects.all()).data,
            status=200,
        )

    def post(self, request):
        data = serializer.DateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if data.is_valid():
            desc = data.data['desc']
            model_instance = models.DateModel.objects.create(
                desc=desc, date=timezone.now().date()
            )
            return Response('Posted!', status=200)
        return Response(
            'Invalid Data, 400 status code error is raised', status=400
        )
```

A database stores a timestamp usually as a binary format. The string format is thus "lost" when you store it. `DATE_FORMAT` only specifies how Django "talks" to the outside world, so in templates, forms, serializers, etc.

Comment: interesting, so i can use `DATE_FORMAT` in case i need to serialize a GET request, so I can see the date in the client side with the desired format, Thanks!